# Neutrino-Antineutrino oscillation

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

I read somewhere about $\nu$-$\bar{\nu}$ oscillations. For this purpose Majorana mass of neutrinos was considered. But I could not understand through the mathematics (involving Lagrangian) how it is happening. Can anyone explain this thing?

Comment: you should give a link of where you read. what.

Answer (score 0):

[Found this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.03797) that shows it is not a standard model situation:

> Heavy neutrino-antineutrino oscillations can naturally appear in mechanisms of low scale neutrino mass generation, where pairs of heavy neutrinos have almost degenerate masses. We discuss the case where the heavy neutrinos are sufficiently long-lived to decay displaced from the primary vertex, such that the oscillations of the heavy neutrinos into antineutrinos can potentially be observed at the (high-luminosity) LHC and at currently planned future collider experiments. The observation of these oscillations would have far-reaching consequences: *it would, for instance, prove the existence of lepton number violation and the Majorana nature of neutrino masses,* and it would allow a deep insight into the nature of the neutrino mass generation mechanism.

italics mine

Neutral particles can oscillate , [see this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon#CP_violation_in_neutral_meson_oscillations). [Majorana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_equation) neutrinos are their own antiparticle and thus could violate lepton number conservation. The field is still open to research.

Aside : [This exposition by Lipkin](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0505141) on neutrino oscillations might help in understanding the experimental reports.

Answer (score -2):

If neutrinos are Majorana fermions, neutrino field is self-adjoint. Then neutrino is the same as antineutrino, and neutrino-antineutrino-oscillation is does not make sense. Then the only way neutrino-antineutrino-oscillation can happen is when neutrinos are Dirac fermions. Unfortunately we don't know whether neutrinos are either Dirac or Majorana fermions. Detection of neutrinoless double beta decay could confirm this in the near future. In the Standard model, neutrinos are Dirac fermions, which would lead to neutrino-antineutrino-oscillations.